# Modify sql statements generated by JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, p6spy

What is the simplest way to intercept and modify sql statements generated by jdbc driver? There is something like P6Spy. According to information from google, an open source framework to support applications that intercept and optionally modify database statements. But last release of the software was back in 2003, website is down, there is no wiki, tutorials etc. Are there any other options?

Thx for help

Comment: not sure if still relevant, but what would you be interested in modifying? The P6Spy might still be an option.

Answer (score 0):

What database?

I recall Oracle added something in version 10 to allow you to patch/rewrite SQL in code you couldn't change.